# Using @progress kendo angular CDN bundles from a webpack client with externals

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

We have a client application build with webpack and we want to use the @progress Kendo Angular UI cdn files. The reason for using CDN is that we have more than 50 applications running as one big application and we use CDN with webpack externals for vendor stuff.

Here is an example of such one file:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/npm/node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-buttons/dist/cdn/js/kendo-angular-buttons.js

But when including any bundle we get following error:

kendo-angular-buttons.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: **Cannot read property '__decorate' of undefined**

How can we include those files? Is there an example of such a mechanism? Most examples use systemjs.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is given through issue on Github by myself:
https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/1148